# cakephp associations conditions

Tags: php, cakephp

i have 3 model, with this relationships:

```
class A extends AppModel {   
    public $belongsTo = array(
        "B" => array(
            'className' => 'B',
            'foreignKey' => 'b_id'
        )
    );
}

class B extends AppModel {    
    public $belongsTo = array(
        "C" => array(
            'className' => 'C',
            'foreignKey' => 'c_id'
        )
    );
}

class C extends AppModel {    
}
```

first, fetch model A records with this code:

```
$this->A->find('all', array('recursive'=>2));
```

when print query log, instead of two left join, this query was seen:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON (A.b_id = B.id)
```

And for each result record, a query to get the C model information like this seen:

```
SELECT * FROM C WHERE id = ?
```

is there a way with a 2 join query to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found when CakePHP does your find via multiple queries, you can force it to get all in a single query by using manual joins:

```
$this->A->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => -1,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'b',
            'alias' => 'B',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array('B.id = A.b_id'),
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'c',
            'alias' => 'C',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array('C.id = B.c_id'),
        ),
    ),
);
```